# Is there a way to force Python string concatenation op for objects?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, operator-overloading

I have some doubts about  having a class and an instance of that class and  concatenating them. The usual is:

```
class MyClass(object):
    # __init__, more code and so on...
    def __str__(self):
        return "a wonderful instance from a wonderful class"

myInstance = MyClass()
message = "My instance is " + str(myInstance) + "."
print(message)
```

And this would go to the `__str__()` method in `MyClass` and successfully print the line, as I remembered from looking the python docs.

But, it is not possible some operator overloading for making possible this?:

```
message = "My instance is " + myInstance + "."
```

I'm just curious, because I thought it could be possible but I can't find this in the python docs. I have an object in this circumstances and thought I could do this shorter, and also implement the operator overloading in the root of a class hierarchy saving the writing in the childs.

I suppose I can't workaround the `str()` call. Can I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement the [`__radd__` hook](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__) to capture being added to another object:

```
def __radd__(self, other):
    return other + str(self)
```

Demo:

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
...     # __init__, more code and so on...
...     def __str__(self):
...         return "a wonderful instance from a wonderful class"
...     def __radd__(self, other):
...         return other + str(self)
...
>>> "My instance is " + MyClass() + "."
'My instance is a wonderful instance from a wonderful class.'
```

You'd probably want to implement [`__add__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__) too, for when your object is the left-hand operator.

However, you should really use [*string formatting*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) to put objects into strings:

```
f"My instance is {myInstance}."
```

or

```
"My instance is {}.".format(myInstance)
```

This calls the [`__format__()` hook](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__format__) on the object, which by default converts your object to a string.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: in this case, because it returns a string, it'll work without `__add__`.

Comment: And the same with __ladd__() if the concat goes `myInstance +"string"`, isnt it?

Comment: @madtyn: yes, in that case `__add__` (no `l`) is called.

Comment: I'm trying this, but finally I'll probably stick to the string format way.

Comment: By the way, I think the f'string' syntax is only available with Python >= 3.6.

Comment: @madtyn: it is, which is why I gave a `str.format()` example as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should adopt the `format()` method for your code. It does that automatically and is far more pythonic then concatenating the string.

```
class MyClass(object):
    # __init__, more code and so on...
    def __str__(self):
        return "a wonderful instance from a wonderful class"

my_instance = MyClass()
print("My instance is {}.".format(my_instance))
```